# Multiple Google App Engine projects share single domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

We're thinking of moving our existing applications to Google App Engine.

Currently we have multiple projects proxyed by Nginx using different locations under 1 single domain. To keep it simple, let's say we have 4 projects:

```
// api
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/api;
}

// desktop web app
location /desktop {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/desktop;
}

// mobile web app
location /mobile {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/mobile;
}

// static landing page
location / {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/landing;
}
```

My questions are:

- What would be the best practice to move those 4 projects to Google App Engine?

Based on what I understand, we have to merge those 4 projects into 1 single project with 4 separate modules. To me, it doesn't sound ideal to have 1 single gigantic project contains everything.

- Is it possible to have single domain serving multiple Google App Engine projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#serving_your_app_on_a_custom_domain) they don't mention if there is a limit or not.  But looking at the steps, I don't see how you could NOT setup the same domain on multiple projects.  As long as you change the CNAME properly, and then make sure that every project redirects internally the right way, everything should work.